# How to view a popup in a datapoint of a line chart in WPF?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpf-controls

I have created one line graph.

**XAML**

```
       <chartingToolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,28,0,0"        Name="chart1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="373" Width="400"  DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

**C#**

```
        System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries LineSeries = new System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
        DataTable dtblClass = new DataTable();
        graphSP spGraph = new graphSP();
        dtblClass = spGraph.ViewAll();

        List<KeyValuePair<String, decimal>> test = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
        foreach (DataRow dra in dtblClass.Rows)
        {
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>((string)dra["customerName"], (decimal)dra["salary"]));
        }
        LineSeries.DependentValuePath = "Value";
        LineSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
        LineSeries.ItemsSource = valueList;
        LineSeries.Title = "Total Salay";
        chart1.Series.Add(LineSeries);
```

How to display a popup in line chart data point instead of Value.